# Найти значения в подмассиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив `section = [[0, 4, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15]];`
И массив `numbers = [2,3,5,8,10,14,15];`

Как определить, какие числа из `numbers` есть в подмассиве `section` в количестве более, чем 1 шт.? 
Например, числа `10, 14` есть в подмассиве `section[2]`, т.е. [2, 6, **10, 14**].

Пробовал так:

```
let result = [];
                    for (let a = 0; a < section.length; a++) {
                        let arr = [];
                        for (let i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
                            if (section[a].includes(numbers[i])) {
                                arr.push(numbers[i])
                            }
                        }
                        if(arr.length>1) {
                             result.push(arr);
                         }
                        console.log(result)
                    }
```

Не сработало. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: а что на выходе должно быть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, массив из чисел. Т.е. `array = [[первое число, второе для первого подмассива], [первое, второе для второго подмассива section],[10, 14]]`

Comment: совсем непонятно... что такое `первое число, второе для первого подмассива` и `первое, второе для второго подмассива section` ? и почему подмассивов стало 3?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Ищу 10, 14 в массиве `section`. Если эти числа находятся в одном подмассиве (как тут `[2, 6, 10, 14]`), то добавляю 10, 14 в результат-array. На выходе - `result = [[10,14]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не знаю, тут, мне кажется, даже рекурсия не нужна.

```js
const section = [[0, 4, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15]];
const numbers = [2,3,5,8,10,14,15];

const result = section
  .map(subs => // map сделает новый массив где значениями  будут пересечения значений numbers и подсекции
      subs.filter(number=>numbers.includes(number)) // просто удалим все значения не входящие в numbers из subs, вернем
  ).filter(r => r.length>1); //я правильно понимаю, что нужно удалить пустые массивы ? (тут же проверим что длина >1)
console.log(result);
```

оставлю для истории, если нужен вдруг список чисел все таки

```js
const section = [[0, 4, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15]];
const numbers = [2,3,5,8,10,14,15];
const result = new Set(); //без Set придется проверять наличие в результатах или держать объект вида {number: true}

for (let subs of section) {
  let found = subs.filter(number=>numbers.includes(number));
  if (found.length>1) {
    found.forEach(number=>result.add(number));
  }
}
console.log(Array.from(result));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var section = [[0, 4, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15]]; 
var numbers = [2,3,5,8,10,14,15];

function diff(sourceArr, compareArr) {
    return sourceArr.filter(function(i) {
      return compareArr.indexOf(i) != -1;
    });
}

var output = [];
for (let i = 0; i < section.length; i++) { 
  var diffArr = diff(section[i], numbers);
  output.push( diffArr.length > 1 ? diffArr : [] );  
}

console.log(output);
```

функция `diff` - для определения совпадения элементов массивов, в котором фильтруем элементы, если они не совпали по условию `indexOf(i) != -1`, где [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) -  возвращает индекс первого вхождения указанного значения в объект и возвращает -1, если значение не найдено.

Далее в цикле к каждому подмассиву `section` применяем функцию. И если количество совпавших элементов >1, то заносим его в `output`, если нет - то заносим пустой массив (если это нужно);

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже не совсем всё понял в твоей задаче. Например, ты пишешь что 
*в количестве более, чем 1 шт.*
 - это значит 2, 3, и т.д., но тебе ведь, судя по примеру, и одно вхождение подходит? 
Также не понял зачем ты во втором цикле ставишь меньше или равно:

```
i <= numbers.length
```

По-моему знака меньше тут достаточно. 
Ну и вот попробуй решение:

```
section = [[0, 4, 8, 12], [1, 5, 9, 13], [2, 6, 10, 14], [3, 7, 11, 15]]; 
numbers = [2,3,5,8,10,14,15];

var result = [];

for (let a = 0; a < section.length; a++) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    let arrStr = ',' + section[a].join() + ',';
    let numbStr =  ',' + numbers[i] + ',';
    if ( ~arrStr.indexOf( numbStr )  ) {
      arr.push(numbers[i])
    }
  }
  arr.length &&  result.push(arr);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Алексей и zb', у вас интересные решения, но почему-то результирующий массив  не включает массивы с вхождениями в первые два подмассива section, там совпадают числа 8 и 5. Если я правильно понял условие, правильный ответ должен выглядеть примерно так: [Array(1), Array(1), Array(3), Array(2)].

Comment: ну в условии же сказано >1

Comment: в условии действительно сказано однозначно, что >1, но далее следует опровергающий например ))). И если мы будем следовать условию > 1, то на выходе при таких данных получим пустой массив. Автор вопроса, только ты знаешь, - правильный ответ [[8][5][2,10,14][3,15]] ? ПС: похоже, я понял, что имел ввиду автор. Отобрать массивы где 2 есть совпадения и больше.